# How do I fade out 1 div and fade in 2 divs, then after 10 seconds of inactivity, fade in the 1st div again, and fade the 2 divs out?

Tags: jquery, fade, user-inactivity

This is my code currently:

```
$(function() {          
        $('#header_left').click(function(){
            $('#header_left_info').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#header_left').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#header_left_back').delay(250).fadeIn('fast');
        });
});
```

(the 250 millisecond delay is so that the fades don't conflict)

Anyway, I'd like to modify this existing code so that it fades #header_left_back out, and #header_left back in - but **only after 10 seconds of inactivity by the user**. This should be simple, but for a web designer with no previous jQuery experience - it's really hard. Betcha you coders can figure this out within 20 seconds!

Thank you!

**This question has been answered. Thanks!**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inactivity"? That the user doesn't move his mouse, doesn't type anything? doesn't click anywhere?

Comment: You've given me an idea - we could just use a 10 second delay, instead of the inactivity. I'll edit the description to make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after something like this:

```
$(function() {          
  $('#header_left').click(function(){
    $('#header_left_info, #header_left').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#header_left_back').delay(250).fadeIn('fast');
  });

  var timer;
  $(document).bind("keypress mousemove", function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
              $('#header_left_back').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#header_left').fadeIn('fast');
              });
            }, 10000);
  });
});
```

After 10 seconds of no mouse movement or keyboard action, it would go the fade in the reverse, swapping them back.  You could add more events if needed, e.g. `mousewheel`, `mousedown`, as specific as you needed to be.  Every time an event happens we start a 10 second countdown, if another event happens we clear the timeout and start the 10 seconds over, so only 10 seconds of idle makes the fades happen in reverse.

Comment: Actually, that's excellent - and works perfectly! Thanks, you've answered the question!

Answer (score 1):

Paul Irish created a [idleTimer](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/) Plugin for jQuery. It's pretty handy.